# Почему показывает такое большое время

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Отсылаю на сервер

```
setInterval(()=> {
                this.sendMessage(this.input.constructInputBitmask().toString());
            }, Math.round(1000 / 30));
```

Сразу же отсылаю обратно ответ

```
private message() {
    var self = this;
    this.socket.on('message', function (msg: string) {
        self.io.emit('message', self.getPosition(msg));
    });
}
```

Время вычисляю так  `return this.player.position.x + '|' + this.player.position.y + '|' + new Date().getTime() + '|' + this.id;`

Пример того что приходит

```
 Point{
    id:4216
    serverTime:1475948760658
    time:1475948761854
    deltaTime:1196
    x:290
    y:130
    }
```

Реальный пинг до VPS  Минимальное = 60мсек, Максимальное = 109 мсек, Среднее = 76 мсек 
Тут то что собственно делал 
http://194.135.88.82:3000/

Comment: как связано _Время вычисляю так  return this.player.position.x + '|' + this.player.position.y + '|' + new Date().getTime() + '|' + this.id;_ с примером того, что приходит?

Comment: @Grundy new Date().getTime() на клиенте и на сервере

Comment: что _new Date().getTime()_?

Comment: @Grundy так получаю время

Comment: Если вы про те поля которые пришли то где в вашем коде видно откуда они берутся эти serverTime и time. Может часы на клиенте и на сервере идут не одинаково (что скорее всего)  а вы эти два времени соответственно на 2х разных компах и получаете

Comment: к тому же неизвестно сколько проходит времени между сохранением числа в строку. отправки его и чтения

Comment: @Mike да на разных компах, как правильно вычислить пинг?

Comment: пусть сервер вернет то же время что получил от клиента, а не свое. а клиент сверит его с временем получения. только это время у вас в секундах, а пинг обычно в миллисекундах меряется, т.е. вряд ли время успеет изменится пока пакет туда сюда ходит

Comment: т.е. по хорошему при измерении вообще фиолетово какое время с другой стороны, засекаете во сколько отправили пакет и во сколько пришел ответ. в самих данных даже время передавать не надо. только вам надо конечно найти время в миллисекундах

Comment: @Mike попробу, только это время в миллисекундах, спс

Comment: @Mike получилось =) как то сам не догнал показывает такой же пинг как в консоли